# How to call imageview in drawerlayout

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.hangout.google.heedbasketball.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:deviceIds= "tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
```

I want a navigation bar in my app but on the home page I want to show images. I guess, I am making some mistake in the layout due to which when I try to run the app, everything gets black.   But as I have called `onclicklistener` on image view, if I click randomly on screen then I can see the video playing.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     android:elevation="4dp"/>


 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/fragement_container" />



 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
     app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:src="@drawable/arena_reaction"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:contentDescription="@string/TODO"
         android:focusable="true"
         />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:contentDescription="@string/TODO"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:src="@drawable/frequentflyer_diop" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView3"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="99dp"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:contentDescription="@string/TODO"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:src="@drawable/frequentflyer_tyus" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView4"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="30dp"


         android:clickable="true"
         android:contentDescription="@string/TODO"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:src="@drawable/monday_memories" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want an imageview inside the navigation drawer? You should share your MainActivity code too.

Comment: No, I want images on the home screen, when I will open the app the navigation bar would be closed

Comment: Oh, then you need to create different fragments and add them to the navigation drawer. Your main fragment will be the homescreen and you can add your images there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the DrawerLayout,  first there is the layout for the main content for the UI (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

In your case :- FrameLayout to contain the main content (which could, for example, by populated by a Fragment at runtime), and a NavigationView for the contents of the navigation drawer.

To do it directly in the above xml , add the linear layout inside/in place of frame layout (better would be to use fragments for various items and frame layout as the container).

Comment: please give a upvote if it helped. thanks for the comment.

Comment: However for the above code I have created individual fragments for all the items in image view and for navigation bar and if I put the frame layout inside the linear layout then I can access the fragments of imageview but can't of navigation bar.

Comment: Fragments are needed for navigation view items and the frame layout would be the container for these fragments. And for the home page as well you need to make a different fragment with a diffferent layout that would show all image views in it.There is no need for fragments for imageview as well. You can set the home fragment to show as your default fragment.

Comment: Actually, with every imageview I have linked a videoview with the help of fragment, in a way that when I click any image it should play the video associated to it. So I guess I need individual fragment for my each imageview as well.

Comment: In that case then you need to add the fragment in a layout eg. frame layout inside the home fragment layout and not in the container frame layout  in the activity layout .